# How to declare a type from an object literal in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an object:

```
const foo = { bar: 123, baz: "lorem" };
```

I would like top obtain the type of this object automatically:

```
type Foo = { bar: number, baz: string };
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `keyof` and `typeof` to construct the `Foo`

```
type Foo = { [P in keyof typeof foo]: typeof foo[P] }
```

Comment: Ok thank you, TIL typescript overrides typeof! After reading the doc, I wonder what is the difference between your answer and ```type Foo = typeof foo``` ?